# Is it impossible to create a function for a created element through coding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('class', 'asd');
parent.appendChild(div);
```

This code basically creates a div and appends it inside the parent element.

```
 $(".asd").hover(function(){
alert("hey");};
```

This one is a function when hovering the created div. But it doesn't work. Any solution?

Comment: When is the hover being attached? Before the element is created, after?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a closing parenthesis:

```
$(".asd").hover(function(){
 alert("hey");
});
```

But really, if you're adding the element dynamically, you should change your `hover` event to one that uses `mouseover` and `mouseout`, and use event delegation so that your event can be caught as it bubbles up the event ladder (or whatever it's called):

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.asd', function () {
  console.log('on')
}).on('mouseout', '.asd', function () {
  console.log('off')
});
```

And you if you're going to use jQuery I'd suggest that you use it for all your DOM manipulation. Using `document.createElement` *and* jQuery is kinda strange.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vfp7306r/8/)

Comment: I higly doubt that is the issue, other than a typo in the code.

Comment: This will resolve the issue if the code in the question runs at load time, and not after.

Comment: yes there is another issue which i found is that div is created dynamically so event delegation should be $(document).on

Comment: @aM-Vee The OP hasn't confirmed that it's being created *after* the event handler is bound; event delegation isn't definitely needed.

Comment: he created div dynamically as you can see in his javascript code on the top

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but you'll need to use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.asd', function() {
    // do stuff here
}).on('mouseleave', '.asd', function() {
    // undo stuff here
});
```

This applies the event listener to some ancestor element that exists on DOM load, and only runs the function if the event target is the element listed as the second argument.

This method allows you to add elements to the page at will without having to create new hover listeners. Any element with class `asd` will have the listeners attached.

If performance is a concern, substitute any ancestor element that's available on DOM load for `document` to reduce the scope of the listener.

http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: Not sure it's possible to say either way whether or not you *need* to use event delegation, since there's nothing in the question to indicate when those two pieces of code are executed, and in which order.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's a safe bet based on the language of the question.

Comment: @epascarello You're right. When I changed hover to click the function worked.

Comment: Looks like it was deprecated.

Comment: I dont' think `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` work. `mouseover` and `mouseout` seem to do the trick.

Comment: mouseenter and mouseleave is what hover use.

Answer (score 0):

Please enclose all the code in `DOM ready` or put the code at the bottom of the page:

**Note:** For this demo, I added `function() {}` as the second parameter of `hover` so that the `alert` does not appear twice ... I could/should have used `focusin` event.

```js
$(function() {
  var parent = $('.parent')[0];
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('class', 'asd');
  parent.appendChild(div);
  $(div).hover(function() {
    alert("hey");
  }, function() {});
});
```

```css
.asd {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

event delegation is wrong on dynamically created div and there is a parentheses mistake
write it like this

```
$(document).on(hover,"asd"function(){
    alert("hey");
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Plus you can leave creating div to jquery

```
parent.appendChild('<div class="asd"></div>');
```

Comment: True, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Question is already answered. Is it so difficult to look at time that you have to down vote it?

Comment: Either an answer answers the question or it doesn't. It's not personal. It's the rules of the game.